# Is there a faster way to calculate color frequency in the browser?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am trying to a calculate color frequency table for images in the browser.

My strategy is

1. load the image in a canvas
2. iterate through the imageData
3. increase the count for the color at the pixel

Like so:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('paper'); 
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
 var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

 var color_table = function(data){
      var h = {}
     
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
           var c = data.slice(i, i + 4).join(':')
           h[c] = h[c] ? h[c] + 1 : 1;
      }
      return h;
 }
```

This is very slow for large images.

I am considering:

- scaling the image down and take the loss of accuracy
- parceling out the work to a number of workers and merging the results

Are these the best strategies? is there a way to parallelize this via WebGL?

Comment: I would create a web service to handle that?  for a small experiment, the browser is fine but once you get serious (large images, parallel processing, high volumes) you need the raw power of a dedicated server

Comment: You can use a js library to decode the image and manually operate on each pixel, skipping the middleman of the canvas?

Comment: How large is large? And how much time? And why a color frequency table? I feel like most image editing apps don't make a color frequency table like you're making, they make channel based histograms, on for r, g, b, a, and maybe one for brightness etc. Much much smaller data. Your code is making an entry for potentially every pixel

Comment: @gman Large is - say -  4223x2805, which takes more than seconds; the frequency table is a first step to a color reduction (quantization), followed by vectorization - I use an Octtree to do the color reduction. I'm using histogram the way ImageMagick seems to use the term as in `convert some_image.jpg -format %c histogram:info:-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You question says "Color frequency" but your code says "histogram"

The code generates a string for each unique color and puts it in an object (a hash map). That potentially 16x more data than the image itself.

- There's the string which is up to 15 characters long as in 255:255:255:255. JavaScript stores strings as 2 bytes per character so that's 30 bytes
- There's a string length
- There's a pointer to the string
- There's a pointer for each entry in the `h` object
- There's a bucket object for each bucket in the object's hash map (assuming it's implemented as a hash map)

Unless the image is over or under saturated most colors will be unique? So you'll end up generating a minimum of 64 bytes of storage per pixel. For a 4k by 4k image that's 1gig of memory just for your color frequency table.

The definition of a histogram is an *approximate* representation of the distribution of numerical data whereas your code is computing an exact representation.

I'm pretty sure apps like Photoshop etc, would generate a histogram based on channels and/or brightness.
Is that's what you really wanted?

Also you haven't defined *large* or *slow*.

Here's a 3k by 4k image.

[image]

Doing a common 256 level per channel histogram using the canvas takes 0.4 seconds on my 6yr old notebook

Example:

```js
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    img.src = url;
  });
}

async function main() {
  const img = await loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOMC.jpg');
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const start = performance.now();
  
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  const data = imageData.data;
  const histogram = [
    new Uint32Array(256),
    new Uint32Array(256),
    new Uint32Array(256),
    new Uint32Array(256),
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    ++histogram[i % 4][data[i]];
  }

  const end = performance.now();
  console.log(`image size: ${img.width}x${img.height}, time: ${((end - start) * 0.001).toFixed(2)}s`);
  
  // show it
  drawHistogram(histogram);
  
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function drawHistogram(histogram) {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const {width, height} = ctx.canvas;
  const colors = [
    '#F00',
    '#0F0',
    '#00F',
  ];
  // only draw r, g, b
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  for (let c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[c];
    const data = histogram[c];
    // hack because there's too much 0 and 255
    data[0] = 0;  data[255] = 0;
    const max = data.reduce((max, v) => Math.max(max, v), 0);
    for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      const v = data[x * data.length / width];
      const h = v / max * height;
      ctx.fillRect(x, height - h + 1, 1, h);
    }
  }
}

main();
```

```css
canvas { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #444;
}

img {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="150"></canvas>
```

It's also faster if we don't separate the channels.

```js
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    img.src = url;
  });
}

async function main() {
  const img = await loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOMC.jpg');
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const start = performance.now();
  
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  const data = imageData.data;
  const histogram = new Uint32Array(256 * 4);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    ++histogram[i % 4 + data[i] * 4];
  }

  const end = performance.now();
  console.log(`image size: ${img.width}x${img.height}, time: ${((end - start) * 0.001).toFixed(2)}s`);
  
  // show it
  drawHistogram(histogram);
  
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function drawHistogram(histogram) {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const {width, height} = ctx.canvas;
  const colors = [
    '#F00',
    '#0F0',
    '#00F',
  ];
  
  // hack because there's too much 0 and 255
  histogram.fill(0, 0, 4);
  histogram.fill(0, histogram.length - 4, histogram.length);
  const numEntries = histogram.length / 4;
  
  function computeMaxForChannel(c) {
    let max = 0;
    for (let i = c; i < histogram.length; i += 4) {
      max = Math.max(max, histogram[i]);
    }
    return max;
  }  
  
  // only draw r, g, b
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  for (let c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[c];
    const max = computeMaxForChannel(c);
    for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      const v = histogram[x * numEntries / width * 4 + c];
      const h = v / max * height;
      ctx.fillRect(x, height - h + 1, 1, h);
    }
  }
}

main();
```

```css
canvas { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #444;
}

img {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="150"></canvas>
```

If you do really want counts for unique colors then you probably also want to count time sorting (not sure what good an unsorted color frequency count would be)

```js
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    img.src = url;
  });
}

async function main() {
  const img = await loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOMC.jpg');
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const start = performance.now();
  
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  // get a view on the data as 32bit values
  const data = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
  // just RGB (no Alpha)
  const histogram = new Uint32Array(256 * 256 * 256);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    ++histogram[data[i] & 0xFFFFFF];
  }

  const sortStart = performance.now();
  // NOTE: sort is commented out below. It's way too slow
  const colors = sortHistogram(histogram);

  const end = performance.now();
  log(`image size: ${img.width}x${img.height}, time: ${((end - start) * 0.001).toFixed(2)}s, sortTime: ${((end - sortStart) * 0.001).toFixed(2)}s`);
  
  // show it
  drawHistogram(histogram, colors);
  
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function sortHistogram(histogram) {
  const colors = new Uint32Array(256 * 256 * 256);
  // sorting 2^24 values this way takes too long
  // so some other algo would be better. For now
  // move all the non-0 counts to the front and only
  // sort those 
  let front = 0;
  let back = colors.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    if (histogram[i]) {
      colors[front++] = i;
    } else {
      colors[back--] = i;
    }
  }
//  quicksort(histogram, colors, 0, front - 1);
  return colors;
}

function quicksort(values, indices, lo, hi) {
  const todo = [[lo, hi]];
  while (todo.length) {
    const [lo, hi] = todo.pop();
    if (lo < hi) {
      const p = partition(values, indices, lo, hi);
      todo.push([lo, p - 1]);
      todo.push([p + 1, hi]);
    }
  }
}

function partition(values, indices, lo, hi) {
  const pivot = values[indices[hi]];
  let i = lo;
  for (let j = lo; j < hi; ++j) {
    if (values[indices[j]] >= pivot) {
      swap(indices, i, j);
      ++i;
    }
  }
  swap(indices, i, hi);
  return i;
}

function swap(indices, i, j) {
  const temp = indices[i];
  indices[i] = indices[j];
  indices[j] = temp;
}

function drawHistogram(histogram, colors) {
  // top 100 colors
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    const color = colors[i];
    const count = histogram[color];
    log(`${i.toString().padStart(3)}: color: #${color.toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}, count: ${count}`);
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = args.join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

main();
```

```css
img { height: 150px; }
pre { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Even though the answer is slightly off due to my usage of the term "histogram" using a `Uint32Array` sped up things considerably - like by a factor of 20

Comment: Well, your solution creates a new string for every pixel, and potentially a new object (a number hanging off the h object) so if you're doing a 4k by 4k image your code is creating 16 million slices, 16 million strings, and the potentially adding 16 million properties to the h object where as my code is all allocation up front.

Comment: Let me also point out though, you can't create the same data you were creating using `Uint32Array`. In order to count all 32bit RGBA colors you'd need a Uint32Array of size 2^32. or 16gig. The browser will fail that allocation. If you drop it to just RGB then you only need to 2^24 which is 64meg but, you'll probably need a way to sort it and I suspect the sorting of 2^24 entries will take a while.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting - this seemed towork well `var histogram = function(data){ var h = new Uint32Array(256 * 256 * 256); for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) { h[data[i] * 65536 + data[i+1] * 256 + data[i+2]]++; } return h }` and since I am ok with working with 8 bit RGB for my purpose, maybe that's ok, unless there is a huge logic flaw in what I am doing and I haven't seen it

Comment: Good point on the sorting though. I am going to look into that - but once I counted the number of pixels per color, I put them into an octtree for pruning and lookup of similar colors (in LAB space), rather than sorting upfront.